# Installing Windows applications/extensions with Amazon CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Amazon's [Windows Roles and Features template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/Windows_Roles_And_Features.template) demonstrates how to install features on a server. But can anyone tell me how would I install an application/feature that is **not** present in this list, such as [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)? I appreciate I could create a custom AMI, but I'm looking to do this entirely at template-level.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example of WebDeploy, you could add this:

```
  "C:\\Webdeploy\\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi" : {
    "source" : "http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/B/3/1B3F8377-CFE1-4B40-8402-AE1FC6A0A8C3/WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi"
 }
```

as a element of this section of the template

```
"WindowsServer": {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Metadata" : {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
      "config" : {
        "files" : {
```

You could then add this command:

```
 "1-installwebdeploy" : {
  "command" : "msiexec.exe /i C:\\Webdeploy\\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL /qn /norestart"
 }
```

to the list of commands.

Comment: Thanks Wade, that looks like exactly what I need. I am however having a bit of difficulty getting the file to download - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750232/why-wont-my-cloudformation-script-download-a-file

Answer (score 2):

There's a slightly easier mechanism if it's just a bog stock msi installation...

```
                    "packages" : {
                        "msi" : {
                            "urlrewrite" : "http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/7/D/67D80164-7DD0-48AF-86E3-DE7A182D6815/rewrite_2.0_rtw_x64.msi"
                        }
                    },
```

Means you don't need the "command" section.