# Why won't my CloudFormation script download a file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need to download a file during the initialisation of my Windows instance. To test this, I'm using the following script to download the Google logo (using a simplified version of the [Windows Roles and Features template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/Windows_Roles_And_Features.template)):

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Description" : "Test download.",

  "Resources" : {

    "InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupDescription" : "Enable RDP",
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
          {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "3389", "ToPort" : "3389", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"}
        ]
      }
    },

    "WindowsServer": {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Metadata" : {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
          "config" : {
            "files" : {
              "c:\\test\\google-logo.png" : {
                "source" : "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },

      "Properties": {
        "InstanceType" : "m1.small",
        "ImageId" : "ami-bbf2e1cf",
        "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup"} ],
        "KeyName" : "POP",
        "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
            "<script>\n",

            "cfn-init.exe -v -s ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" }, 
            " -r WindowsServer",
            " --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",

            "</script>"
        ]]}}
      }
    },

    "WindowsServerWaitHandle" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle"
    },

    "WindowsServerWaitCondition" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition",
      "DependsOn" : "WindowsServer",
      "Properties" : {
        "Handle" : {"Ref" : "WindowsServerWaitHandle"},
        "Timeout" : "1800"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This finishes executing with no error... and no file. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jonathon,

I tried your template and the file downloaded successfully for me. You can check the cfn logs on the instance. They are in `c:\cfn\log\`. My cfn-init.log shows:

```
2013-07-19 21:30:18,269 [DEBUG] Parent directory c:\test does not exist, creating
2013-07-19 21:30:18,269 [DEBUG] Writing content to c:\test\google-logo.png
2013-07-19 21:30:18,269 [DEBUG] Retrieving contents from http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png
2013-07-19 21:30:18,316 [DEBUG] No mode specified for c:\test\google-logo.png
2013-07-19 21:30:18,316 [WARNING] Unsupported OS for setting owner/group: nt
```

And my cfn-wire.log shows:

```
2013-07-19 21:30:18,269 [DEBUG] Request: GET http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png [headers: {'Accept-Encoding': 'identity, deflate, compress, gzip', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/0.11.1'}]
2013-07-19 21:30:18,302 [DEBUG] Response: 200 http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png [headers: {'content-length': '18946', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'expires': 'Fri, 19 Jul 2013 21:30:20 GMT', 'server': 'sffe', 'last-modified': 'Mon, 25 Mar 2013 19:02:15 GMT', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=31536000', 'date': 'Fri, 19 Jul 2013 21:30:20 GMT', 'content-type': 'image/png'}]
```

Comment: Soon after it worked for me too - bizarre. Thanks for taking the time to check.